# Route Login is not defined in Laravel

Tags: laravel, routes, jwt

I have one problem, why when I accessing the login/register page always given `Route [login] is not defined` I already try to search for my problem and nothing result happen, I will give my detail in bellow.

**User Controller** :

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->middleware('auth:api', ['except' => ['login', 'register']]);
}
```

in that case, I wanna get the token and user detail after successful login, and it's working I got the token and I got the user detail, but when I logout and back into the login or register page, it's error, and for the message `Route [login] is not defined`, but when I delete the `__construct()` it's working, but when I login again with my same account, the token and detail user is giving null value, I will give my route detail in the bellow.

**Route :**

```
Route::get('/', function () {
   return redirect('auth');
});

Route::get('auth', 'UserController@viewLogin');
Route::get('register', 'UserController@viewRegister');
Route::get('dashboard', 'DashboardController@view');

Route::group(['prefix' => 'auth'], function () {
   Route::post('login', 'UserController@login');
   Route::post('logout', 'UserController@logout');
   Route::get('user-profile', 'UserController@userProfile')->middleware('jwt.verify');
});
```

**Update Login Post :**

```
$user_data = [
    'email' => $email,
    'password' => $password,
    'is_active' => 1
];

$user_credentials = JWTAuth::attempt($user_data);

if (!$user_credentials) {
    return response()->json([
        'error_message' => 'Your account is not registered yet, please register first'
    ], 401);
} else {
    return response()->json([
        'user' => JWTAuth::user(),
        'token' => $user_credentials,
        'success_message' => "Login Successfuly",
    ]);
    
}
```

**Form Login :**

```
<form action="javascript:;" method="POST" autocomplete="off">
    @csrf
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="font-weight-normal">Email</label>
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="user@mail.com">
            <div class="input-group-append">
                <div class="input-group-text input-group-email">
                    <span class="fas fa-envelope"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="text-danger" id="email-err"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="font-weight-normal">Password</label>
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="********">
            <div class="input-group-append">
                <div class="input-group-text input-group-password">
                    <span class="fas fa-eye clicked" id="show-hide"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="text-danger" id="password-err"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <button type="submit" id="login-process" class="btn btn-block" disabled>Sign In</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Javascript :

```
$("#login-process").on('click', function () {
    const emailValue = $("input[name='email']").val();
    const passwordValue = $("input[name='password']").val();

    $.ajax({
        url: "auth/login",
        method: "POST",
        async: true,
        data: {
            email: emailValue,
            password: passwordValue,
        },
        success: function (success) {
            // describe one by one success method
            const accessToken = success['token'];
            const successMessage = success['success_message'];

            localStorage.setItem('monitoring-barang', accessToken);
            window.location.replace('dashboard');
        },
    });
});
```

Comment: you access this url "http://yourweb/auth/login" ?

Comment: just `myweb/auth`, for login page and not login process sir

Comment: Show your code when you write route for post login in form action. <form action="this route???"></form>

Comment: for route post I use this sir : `Route::post('login', 'UserController@login');`

Comment: your error because post login route is missing or you wrote it wrong. show your code in this section <form action="this route???"></form>

Comment: done sir I already update my question

Comment: your construct in controller have many function which is require auth:api middleware except function login & register? I think only logout and userProfile need auth:api middleware.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227988/discussion-between-gzai-kun-and-luckalip).

Answer (score 2):

This error is probably related to your XHR request not having the correct `Accept` header (which should be `application/json`).

This will make the `auth` middleware respond, but even though you combined it with `api`, the lacking `Accept` header will make the `web` middleware group respond with it's authentication.

This will effectively fire the `redirectTo` method in `app/Http/Middleware/Authenticate.php` where, [on line 18](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/8.x/app/Http/Middleware/Authenticate.php#L18), there's a reference to the route named `login`, a route you have explicitly not added by adding the `except` parameter to the middleware method in your controller.

The solution is to either comment out redirect out, make a dummy route for the purpose or implement a better strategy like [Sanctum](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum)

Comment: Alright sir thanks for advice, I will try first